# Automatically refresh image every 2 seconds android

Tags: android, timer, countdowntimer

So I am trying to have a picture automatically refresh every 2 seconds.  I've tried the handler/timer method, but I'm confused as how to call it and for some reason can not get it to actually refresh...

```
private void refreshPicture(final String refreshRate, final String userName, final String userPicture) {

    final Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            long millis = Long.parseLong(refreshRate);
            int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
            int minutes = seconds / 60;
            seconds = seconds % 60;

            //my method where i refresh image
            getUserPicture(userName, userPicture);

            timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to initiate the first call of the runnable. After defining the `timerRunnable`, you have to call `timerHandler.post(timerRunnable);` once. Also, if you want to have it refreshed every 2 seconds, you have to put 2000 instead of 500 as value in `postDelayed()`.

Don’t forget to call `timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable)` when you want to stop refreshing.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that.  Thanks for the answer and pointing it out, works like a charm.  Suppose a user exits out of the app (but it is still in the background), does that mean it will continue to be called unless I put timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable) in the onPause method?

Comment: Yes, unless the app is being killed by the system.